# Implement finish event handler of custom writable stream class

Tags: node.js, writable

Assume that `customWS` is a writable stream ..

```
  util.inherits(customWS, stream.Writable);
```

we implement our logic to handle the writes in the `_write()` like below ..

```
  customWS.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
    // ...
  }
```

now to use the `customWS` class, we would do something like below ..

```
  aReadableStream.pipe(new customWS()).on('finish', callback);
```

so what are the parameters of the `callback` function ??

can i pass a `callback` like ..

```
  function(data) {
    // ...    
  }
```

.. or is it fixed ??

if it's not fixed then how to implement such callback in the `customWS` class ??

is there anything like ..

```
  // in the implementation of customWS class
  customWS.prototype._finish = function(user_specified_callback) {
    user_specified_callback(some_data_say_a_bool_val);
  }

  // in the code, where i use the customWS class
  aReadableStream.pipe(new customWS()).on('finish', function(flag) {
    if (flag) {
      console.log('yes');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically shouldn't need to do anything to support `finish()`. The `finish` event and its signature is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish). It does not have any parameters, it's merely a notification that the writable stream has "closed" and cannot be written to anymore.

If as the stream implementor you need to specifically do something right before the "closing" of the writable stream, you are more or less out of luck as of this writing. There is a [PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2314) to add this functionality to Writable streams. If you were implementing a Transform stream, you'd have `_flush()` which is what you'd want, but that's only useful if you're implementing a duplex stream (not Writable only).